# How to increase the image size in paint

Tags: pdf, paint

Is it possible to increase the 40KB jpeg to 40 MB?

If have tried by adding multiple images to paint

It was not working

Please help me to resolve

Then I want to create a pdf which should have more than 25MB

Comment: Why do you want to increase the image size from 40KB to 40MB?

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.